# Deleting multiple columns from a numpy array

Tags: numpy

I have array of random columns, that has to be deleted from numpy array. When i am trying below code, that many number of columns are not getting deleted. Any suggestion?

```
np.array([np.delete(image[row], columns[row].astype(int), axis=0) for row in range(height)])
```

Comment: give us a  [mcve]

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure what a few things in the example are, like image[row], and columns[row] But the below example words to delete multiple columns. With the example `np.delete(n,[0,2],1)` That's saying for array n, delete the first(0) and the third(2) line where the axis=1

```
n = np.array([
        [2,3,4,6],
        [3,3,0,8],
        [8,4,1,0],
        [9,4,2,0]])

print(np.delete(n,[0,2],1))
```

output

```
[[3 6]
 [3 8]
 [4 0]
 [4 0]]
```